# How to limit movement of a IK-chain (armature) to one plane?

Tags: armature

I build a Zig-Zag-mechanic from a bone chain and enabled Inverse Kinematics for
the first bone and the whole chain.
When contracted it should look like this: VVVVVVV
Currently it is a straight line of bones like this: ---------------
Now the fun part ;)

How can I force the bones to always build this ZigZag-Pattern if the IK-enabled bone is moved directly towards the opposite of the chain?
How can I force the bone chain into one plane of movement?
How can I force the bone chain to build a half circle if the IK-enabled
bone is not directly moved towards the end of the chain?
The movement of the IK-enabled bone always is in the same plane as the rest
of the bones.
I tried "Limit rotation" but this does not work for me (which either could
mean, that I did something wrong or "Limit rotation" is the wrong tool.

How can I acchieve what I want to do?

Comment: hello, I think you should make some screenshots or share your file so that it's clearer

Answer (score 1):

The IK constraint generally ignores other constraints, so using limit constraints won't work.

However each bone has its own IK settings on their properties panel that allow you to limit rotations etc, for more information see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/posing/bone_constraints/inverse_kinematics/introduction.html#bone-ik-panel

Answer (score 1):

If we start with bones that lie in a plane, and we only ever move our IK target in that plane, then the bones will never rotate out of that plane.  Topmost is rest position:

[image]

So then all that we have to do is specify the plane we want them to lie in by orienting the parent the of the first bone in the chain.

However, you might not just want them to lie in a plane, but for them to lie in a line, instead of curving like they do.  For that, I would recommend using multiple 2-bone chains, and parenting each's IK target to a stretch-to bone:

[image]

Here, as the we move the control (the final IK target), the stretch bone tracks it, and positions our IK targets in a line, equidistantly spaced between the root and the control, so all of our IK bones behave nicely.