# Limit movement of IK Controller vs Armature

Tags: armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

Before I start, I've already seen [How to limit movement of a IK-chain (armature) to one plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115818/how-to-limit-movement-of-a-ik-chain-armature-to-one-plane) which kinda looks like my problem but honestly, didn't understand much.

I'm not very familiar with armature so I'll try to explain poblem as much as I can.

Have this very simple `armature` with three bones. Last bone (marked as `Bottom Bone`) is assigned to empty object - IK controller. Empty object has to follow path (`Bezier curve`).

[image]

This works as expecting except one thing I don't like. Eveything is fine when IK Controller moves along Y and Z axis. But when it start moving along X bones get bendy, they rotate on joints. That makes problem when I connect bones to actual hard-surface mesh (mechanical device).

I'd like to figure out a way to limit that movement a bit.

What I need is to find a way to rotate entire armature around starting point of `Top Bone` when IK controller moves along X, and let it freely move along Y and Z. Point I've marked with red has static location and should rotate only along Z when IK controller is moving along X, and around local X when IK goes along Y or Z.

[image]

I figured out one complicated way with two same paths, one scaled to zero by X to be used by IK Controller and another one scaled to zero by Z which can be used by another parent empty that captures armature. As you guess, that makes a lot of problems when I need to edit path and entire structue looks kinda messy.

I know there are some limitations about Inverse Kinematics, and my lack of experience makes me unable to figure out some simpler solution. Just want to avoid bones rotating around their local Y and Z axis.

[image]

I know that my approach is probably wrong and maybe has no sense for some of you experienced guys. I am pretty much noob in this kind of work and kicking my head against the wall for days trying to figure out solution by myself. Really desparate.

My mind goes in a way to somehow limit rotation of each individual bone but cant say is that possible and if it is, where to look.

Suggest me anything, need to make it work and learn something.

If you need more details feel free to comment. I've really tried to do my best.

Comment: Not very confident what you're after.  Have you consider IK angle limits/locks on the two bones you don't want to rotate in local Y? Look in properties/bone/IK.

Comment: @Nathan Didn't know that exists actually. I'm going for it now. Sounds exactly like what I need. Problem is that bones are connected to hard surface mesh (metal parts with horizontal cylinders as joints (everything should rotate around these cylinders). Now it gets bendy so parts get weird shape when IK controller moves along X axis because all bones rotate in all directions. Hope that you suggested works for me and spare me more time of suffering.

Comment: @Nathan YES MAN. That's it. Had a bit to work with it but keeps things simple and works really fantastic. Thanx a million. I feel st*pid now, but that's how it is when you learning.